# Toggle multiple KML/KML layers in google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

I have been tying to toggle KML layers in google maps. I have had it setup such that only one layer shows up with out any toggle button. I followed many examples online but none seem to work. The code I have setup so far is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var layers=[];
layers[0] = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://wrf1.geology.um.maine.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5254.kml',
 {preserveViewport: true});
layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://wrf1.geology.um.maine.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5938.kmz',
{preserveViewport: true});
var map;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5028910, 13.41032740);
    var myOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    }

function toggleLayers(i)
{
        if(layers[i].getmap()==null){
                kmlLayer01.setMap(null);
        }
        else{
                    layers[i].setMap(null);
            }
}


</script> </head>
<body onload="initialize()">
Layer1 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" onclick="toggleLayers(0);"/>
Layer2 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" onclick="toggleLayers(1);"/>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. the posted code does not include the API, this is missing:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   ```
2. There are a few typos:

- javascript is case sensitive getmap  is not a valid method name, should be getMap.
- kmlLayer01 is not defined, probably should be layers[i]

  ```
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var layers=[];

        layers[0] = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://wrf1.geology.um.maine.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5254.kml',
        {preserveViewport: true});

        layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://wrf1.geology.um.maine.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5938.kmz',
        {preserveViewport: true});
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5028910, 13.41032740);
            var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 3,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
        }

        function toggleLayers(i)
        {

          if(layers[i].getMap()==null) {
             layers[i].setMap(map);
          }
          else {
             layers[i].setMap(null);
          }
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers("+i+") [setMap("+layers[i].getMap()+"] returns status: "+layers[i].getStatus()+"<br>";
        }


        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="initialize()">
        Layer1 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" onclick="toggleLayers(0);"/>
        Layer2 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" onclick="toggleLayers(1);"/>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px; width:600px;"></div>
        <div id="status"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
  ```

[working example](http://geocodezip.com/v3_SO_KmlLayerToggle.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var layers = [];

layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSouthern_kml.xml",
  /*'http://wrf1.geology.um.maine.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5254.kml', original KML no longer available */
  {
    preserveViewport: true
  });

layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSoutheastern_kml.xml",
  /* 'http://wrf1.geology.um.maine.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5938.kmz', original KML no longer available */
  {
    preserveViewport: true
  });
var map;

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -112 /*52.5028910, 13.41032740 */ );
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

function toggleLayers(i) {

  if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers(" + i + ") [setMap(" + layers[i].getMap() + "] returns status: " + layers[i].getStatus() + "<br>";
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
Layer1
<input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" onclick="toggleLayers(0);" />Layer2
<input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" onclick="toggleLayers(1);" />
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px; width:600px;"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ravin,

If you have two different maps, pass a variable for the map into the function, e.g

```
function toggleLayers(i,theMap)
{

 if(layers[i].getMap()==null) {
     layers[i].setMap(theMap);
  }
  else {
     layers[i].setMap(null);
}
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers("+i+") [setMap("+layers[i].getMap()+"] returns status: "+layers[i].getStatus()+"<br>";
}
```

Lea.