# Function to turn KML layer on/off

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

This is my first time posting here. I am new in working with Javascript or Google Maps API. I have a map with one KML layer, and I want to create a checkbox that will turn the layer on or off when clicked. I have seen a lot of examples on the web, but nothing seems to work in my application. Here is the code:

```
(function() {
window.onload = function() {

    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.65, 22.64), 
        zoom: 10, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
                google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            ]       
        },
        streetViewControl: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

    var kmlUrl = 'http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/trasee.kml';
        var kmlOptions = {
        suppressInfoWindows: false,
        preserveViewport: false,
    };

    var trasee = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions).setMap(map);

}
})();
```

I have no idea what function to create to toggle the visibility of the layer, altough I've created a checkbox in the HTML file:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="straturi" onClick="togglefunction()" />
```

Could you give me any advice?

Best regards,
Alexandru

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle multiple KML/KML layers in google maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409598/toggle-multiple-kml-kml-layers-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle function should be something like

```
var toggleKml=function(layer) {
    if(layer.getMap()===null) {
        layer.setMap(map)
    } else {
        layer.setMap(null)
    }
};
```

And it needs to be defined in the same context as map and trasee, otherwise it won't see those objects. In your case, you would call it with trasee as parameter

```
toggleKml(trasee);
```

Comment: You mean, my answer worked or you found another way?

Comment: Yes, I have used your function.