# How to add Google Earth KML file to html iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, kml, google-earth

Basically, I am trying to add/show my KML file on my Google Earth div to my website. I call my file "satellites.kml".

```
<!-- html code starts...-->

 <p><iframe 
       name="myKMLEarth" 
       src="/getrack/satellites.kml"
       height="440" 
       width="100%" 
       frameborder="0" 
       scrolling="no">
 </iframe></p>

<!-- html code continues ...-->
```

When the page loads, it downloads my KML instead of opening it up in the iframe. Should I not use src to link to the KML file? Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Display the contacts of your .kml file as plaintext?

Comment: I am trying to add my KML layer to my google earth that is displayed on the website.

Comment: Why are you using an iframe? You can just add `satellites.kml` as a new layer. See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409598/toggle-multiple-kml-kml-layers-in-google-maps-api-v3) for how someone else did it

Comment: i tried to do this before, and it doesn't work on localhost. when i uploaded to a server, and add `src="http://someserver.com/my.kml"` that workred. i do not know, is it your problem or not. what console says?

Comment: and sorry, i forgot to mentioned, i've did it in google map api3. as i see, it's not that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the Google Maps JavaScript API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=es

You have to attach a `google.maps.KmlLayer` to a Map.

Put the API script in the `<head>`

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

Create a div like:

```
<div id="google-map" class="google-map"></div>
```

Then, use this JS code before `</body>`.  Set your latitude, longitude and path to KML file.

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(YOUR_LAT,YOUR_LNG), //Set your latitude, longitude
          zoom: 19,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
          scrollwheel: false
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), mapOptions); // get the div by id

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'PATH/TO/FILE.kml' // Set the KML file
        });

        // attach the layer to the map
        ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    }

    // load the map
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to open the KML in another application or using a plugin. The browser does not know how to display the file in an iframe, so it simply downloads it.

[From Google's KML Documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/):
"Many applications display KML, including Google Earth, Google Maps, Google Maps for mobile, NASA WorldWind, ESRI ArcGIS Explorer, Adobe PhotoShop, AutoCAD, and Yahoo! Pipes."

I don't 100% understand what you are trying to do, so I can't be sure if this is what you are looking for, but this question might point you in the right direction: [How to Embed KML files (Google Earth) into a website without the google gadget?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48862/how-to-embed-kml-files-google-earth-into-a-website-without-the-google-gadget)

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK to use Google Maps instead of Google Earth, you can do it by using KMLLayer as given here: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/

FYI: Google has deprecated Google Earth API - https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index