# toggle kml in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a map with a single KML layer. But once it's embedded on a website, I need the user to be able to toggle the KML on and off. I have tried to use suggested code from other questions to make this work, but I'm not having any luck. I'd really appreciate anyone's help in finding a solution to this.

Here is my code. You'll notice that I also have a draggable marker, which when it's moved, changes the GPS co-ordinates at the bottom of the map:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function geocodePosition(pos) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos
      }, function(responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
          updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
          updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
        }
      });
    }

    function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
      document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat(),
        latLng.lng()
      ].join(', ');
    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
      document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function initialize() {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.742023, 29.462218);
      var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.460136, 31.3189074);
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerPosition,
        title: 'Point A',
        map: map,
        draggable: true
      });

      // Update current position info.
      updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
      geocodePosition(latLng);

      // Add dragging event listeners.
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('DRAGGING...');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('DRAGGING...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('DRAG & DROP THE MARKER ONTO YOUR DESIRED PROPERTY');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
      });

      var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer();

      var kmlUrl = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29079095/Limpopo_Hunting_Zones/Zones_2015.kml';
      var kmlOptions = {
        suppressInfoWindows: false,
        preserveViewport: true,
        map: map
      };
      var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
    }

     // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #mapCanvas {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
      float: top;
    }
    #infoPanel {
      float: top;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #infoPanel div {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>MARKER STATUS:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>DRAG & DROP THE MARKER ONTO YOUR DESIRED PROPERTY.</i>
    </div>
    <b>GPS CO-ORDINATES:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How are you expecting them to toggle the KML? I don't see a checkbox or button to do that (or any code that might enable that functionality).  What do you mean by "I have tried to use suggested code from other questions to make this work"?  I don't see any of those attempts.

Comment: I've deleted all of the suggested code as it would result in the map not working. So just posted code that I was able to get right. I'm currently trying to use some iteration of the code presented here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409598/toggle-multiple-kml-kml-layers-in-google-maps-api-v3), but it's not working. I'm very new at this.

Comment: Please post the code where you attempted to make it work, but couldn't.  The question you linked to works for me (once I fixed the KML that was removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the map to be global to use it inside functions run by click listeners.

Working code snippet, based of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409598/toggle-multiple-kml-kml-layers-in-google-maps-api-v3):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var layers=[];
    layers[0] = new  google.maps.KmlLayer("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29079095/Limpopo_Hunting_Zones/Zones_2015.kml",
 {preserveViewport: true});

    function toggleLayers(i)
    {
        if(layers[i].getMap()==null){
           layers[i].setMap(map);
        }
        else {
           layers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }

    function geocodePosition(pos) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos
      }, function(responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
          updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
          updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
        }
      });
    }

    function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
      document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat(),
        latLng.lng()
      ].join(', ');
    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
      document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function initialize() {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.742023, 29.462218);
      var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.460136, 31.3189074);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerPosition,
        title: 'Point A',
        map: map,
        draggable: true
      });

      // Update current position info.
      updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
      geocodePosition(latLng);

      // Add dragging event listeners.
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('DRAGGING...');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('DRAGGING...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('DRAG & DROP THE MARKER ONTO YOUR DESIRED PROPERTY');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
      });
/*
      var kmlUrl = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29079095/Limpopo_Hunting_Zones/Zones_2015.kml';
      var kmlOptions = {
        suppressInfoWindows: false,
        preserveViewport: true,
        map: map
      };
      var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
*/
    }

     // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  <style>
    #mapCanvas {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
      float: top;
    }
    #infoPanel {
      float: top;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #infoPanel div {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
Layer1 <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" onclick="toggleLayers(0);"/>
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <div id="address"></div>
    <b>MARKER STATUS:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>DRAG & DROP THE MARKER ONTO YOUR DESIRED PROPERTY.</i>
    </div>
    <b>GPS CO-ORDINATES:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I see it works now! I think I was going wrong in a few areas. For starters, I was defining the KML incorrectly. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!