# Toggle kml layers in Maps API (kml not displaying anymore)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am building a map in API and want a toggle clecklist for multiple kml files (categories) where the map loads displaying all, and then user can toggle on/off whichever they want. I got it to work yesterday with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348218/toggle-kml-layers-in-maps-api) and @geocodezip [geocodezip](http://user:1210329). The map is loading and I have checkboxes but the kml is not displaying anymore and I can't figure it out. I've used his example xmls below but yesterday I had it working with my own kml. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```js
<script 
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">   

var layers = [];

layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSouthern_kml.xml',
  {
    preserveViewport: true
  });

layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSoutheastern_kml.xml',
  {
    preserveViewport: true
  });

// end layers to toggle 
// intialize 

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.601987, -122.333624);
  var myOptions = {
    mapId: "f36e677014a7abf2",
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

 loadKml = function(opts, map) {
    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer();
    opts.preserveViewport = true;
    if (map) {
      opts.map = map;
    }

   google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
      var map = this.getMap(),
        bounds = map.get('kmlBounds') || this.getDefaultViewport();

      bounds.union(this.getDefaultViewport());
      map.set('kmlBounds', bounds);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    layer.setOptions(opts);
    return layer;
  };

  function toggleLayers(i) {
      if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
      } else {
        layers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      google.maps.event.addListener(layers[i], 'status_changed', function() {

        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers(" + i + ") [setMap(" + layers[i].getMap() + "] returns status: " + layers[i].getStatus() + "<br>";
      });
    }
// end toggle layers
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('layer_01'), 'click', function(evt) {
    toggleLayers(0);
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('layer_02'), 'click', function(evt) {
    toggleLayers(1);
  });
// toggle layers at the beginning
  toggleLayers(0);
  toggleLayers(1);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

```css
<style>
#map_canvas {width: 100%; height: 1000px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
#check_boxes {margin: auto; width: 50%; padding: 25px; text-align: center; }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="check_boxes">

<b>SHOPPING</b> <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" checked="checked"/>
<b>DINING</b> <input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" checked="checked" /></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

This is what I am posting into my page and the checkbox displays but no map at all:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#check_boxes {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDEG25mWrlEMJMLAeqPwEPGsPL6_tfxe0w&v=weekly&callback=InitMap&libraries=&v=beta&map_ids=f36e677014a7abf2">
</script>

<script>    

var layers = [];

layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSouthern_kml.xml', {
  preserveViewport: true
});

layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSoutheastern_kml.xml', {
  preserveViewport: true
});

// end layers to toggle 
// intialize 
var map;

function initialize() {
  console.log("initialize");
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.601987, -100.333624);
  var myOptions = {
    mapId: "f36e677014a7abf2",
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  loadKml = function(opts, map) {
    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer();
    opts.preserveViewport = true;
    if (map) {
      opts.map = map;
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
      var map = this.getMap(),
        bounds = map.get('kmlBounds') || this.getDefaultViewport();

      bounds.union(this.getDefaultViewport());
      map.set('kmlBounds', bounds);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    layer.setOptions(opts);
    return layer;
  };

  function toggleLayers(i) {
    console.log("toggleLayers(" + i + ")");
    if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
      layers[i].setMap(map);
    } else {
      layers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[i], 'status_changed', function() {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers(" + i + ") [setMap(" + layers[i].getMap() + "] returns status: " + layers[i].getStatus() + "<br>";
    });
  }
  // end toggle layers
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('layer_01'), 'click', function(evt) {
    toggleLayers(0);
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('layer_02'), 'click', function(evt) {
    toggleLayers(1);
  });
  // toggle layers at the beginning
  toggleLayers(0);
  toggleLayers(1);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="check_boxes">
    <b>SHOPPING</b> <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" checked="checked" />
    <b>DINING</b> <input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" checked="checked" /></div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div id="status"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet has issues (`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"`, `"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"`).  It is working in both the fiddles and the code snippet in my answer to the [question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348218/toggle-kml-layers-in-maps-api).

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know what that means or what the error is referencing. Like I said, I had it working yesterday (and its displaying the map and checkboxes on my staging server page, the kml is just not displaying). Would you be able to take a look and let me know whats wrong with my code? Thanks so much!

Comment: What did you change?  If you would like help, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. The code snippet in your question has obvious syntax errors that are not likely to be the actual problem (since the code in my answer to the question that you started from still works)

Comment: I suspect all I fixed were the issues you created pasting the code into the Stack Snippet.  But my answer is the fixed code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**Working code snippet:**

```js
var layers = [];

layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSouthern_kml.xml', {
  preserveViewport: true
});

layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSoutheastern_kml.xml', {
  preserveViewport: true
});

// end layers to toggle 
// intialize 
var map;

function initialize() {
  console.log("initialize");
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.601987, -100.333624);
  var myOptions = {
    mapId: "f36e677014a7abf2",
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  loadKml = function(opts, map) {
    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer();
    opts.preserveViewport = true;
    if (map) {
      opts.map = map;
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
      var map = this.getMap(),
        bounds = map.get('kmlBounds') || this.getDefaultViewport();

      bounds.union(this.getDefaultViewport());
      map.set('kmlBounds', bounds);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    layer.setOptions(opts);
    return layer;
  };

  function toggleLayers(i) {
    console.log("toggleLayers(" + i + ")");
    if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
      layers[i].setMap(map);
    } else {
      layers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[i], 'status_changed', function() {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers(" + i + ") [setMap(" + layers[i].getMap() + "] returns status: " + layers[i].getStatus() + "<br>";
    });
  }
  // end toggle layers
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('layer_01'), 'click', function(evt) {
    toggleLayers(0);
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('layer_02'), 'click', function(evt) {
    toggleLayers(1);
  });
  // toggle layers at the beginning
  toggleLayers(0);
  toggleLayers(1);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#check_boxes {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="check_boxes">
    <b>SHOPPING</b> <input type="checkbox" id="layer_01" checked="checked" />
    <b>DINING</b> <input type="checkbox" id="layer_02" checked="checked" /></div>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Im sorry im a newb at js and I really appreciate your help. I am using wordpress btw so this is what I pasted into a text column:

Comment: What is what you pasted into a text column? What does that have to do with your question? Not sure how using WordPress should matter.

Comment: I just "answered" with what I pasted

Comment: Not sure what that means.  Is that the answer to your question? If not, it shouldn't be posted as once.  It probably should be an edit to your question.

Comment: I meant I used answer to paste what Im using since it wouldnt fit in a comment. I'll edit the op but im still confused as to why the map isnt loading but seems to work in the snippet/fiddle.

Comment: The html file you posted in your question works fine: http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20200812_kmlLayer.html  My guess is your problem is with wordpress, if you look at the page being served by wordpress it is probably different from the html one you are expecting.  Try viewing source on that page.

Comment: I noticed you had changed my map canvas height to a percentage and for some reason WP or the theme or whatever didn't like that. I happened to try switching that back to px and voila, works perfectly. I now have 7 layers and everything is working well. Thanks so much geocodezip!

Comment: I changed that because it works better in the jsfiddle and code snippets. You probably didn't have a size on one of the parent elements of the map `<div>`, but you probably want your own css for that on your page anyway.